# Error Red5 server to streaming files who include cover art or album art in java

Tags: java

I am using red5 server for streaming mp3 file or others format file. It work fine if my file does not include any cover art or album art. If it include cover art or album art I get below exception.

```
[ERROR] [pool-4-thread-2] org.red5.server.messaging.InMemoryPullPullPipe - exception when pulling message from provider
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:235) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer.position(AbstractIoBuffer.java:368) [mina-core-2.0.0-RC1.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.mp3.impl.MP3Reader.analyzeKeyFrames(MP3Reader.java:603) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.mp3.impl.MP3Reader.<init>(MP3Reader.java:242) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.io.mp3.impl.MP3.getReader(MP3.java:48) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.stream.provider.FileProvider.init(FileProvider.java:232) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.stream.provider.FileProvider.pullMessage(FileProvider.java:126) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.messaging.InMemoryPullPullPipe.pullMessage(InMemoryPullPullPipe.java:70) [red5.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.stream.PlayEngine$PullAndPushRunnable.run(PlayEngine.java:1538) [red5.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [na:1.6.0_20]
```

Comment: Are you trying to debug red5 or are you using it and wonder why this is happening? If it's the later, then this is the wrong site.

Comment: I am using Red5 server for streaming mp3 file run in Flow player.
It run fine when file donot contains cover art picture or album art picture.